# How to make for() loop take less time (android)?

Tags: android, optimization, iteration

I am making an app for android devices. There is a function in my app which has 2 "for loops" which iterate 3200 times each, accessing a 53 KB .txt file(which contains 3200 lines) and compare a string with each line, one line per iteration. The "for loops" also contain BufferedReader(), InputStreamReader(), InputStream() and StringTokenizer(). So it takes around 8 seconds for it to process that function, when I run the app on the emulator. This is inacceptable. How can I reduce the time required to, like, half a second, or max. 1 second? Thanks!
edit:Here's is the part of my program with the 2 for loops:

```
else if(a==2){
        String z="";
        try{
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES.txt");
            InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(iz);

            int v=0;

            v=count("USCOUNTIES.txt");//counts number of lines in the .txt file
        //finding no. of counties to be displayed
            int counter=0;
            String pos;
            pos=Integer.toString(position);
            try{
            for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
                z=bis.readLine();
                //int x=pos.length();
                boolean a;
                //using stringtokenizer
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(z, ","); 
                String substring;
                substring=(String) st.nextElement();
                a=substring.equals(pos);
                if(a==true){

                    counter=counter+1;

                }
            }}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            String array1[]=new String[counter];

            try{
                InputStream ig = getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES.txt");
                InputStreamReader ia=new InputStreamReader(ig);
                BufferedReader bos = new BufferedReader(ia);
            int j=0;
            for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
                z=bos.readLine();
                String[] split = z.split(",");
                if(split[0].equals(pos)){
                    array1[j]=split[1];
                    j=j+1;
                }

            }}
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Honestly, 8 seconds to read 3200 files with 3200 lines each line by line is pretty good.

Comment: It is a single 3200 lined file. And it is iterated 3200 times. Any suggestion you might have? I do this to put some of the file's data    in a list.

Comment: Why are you re-reading the same file **3200 times**?

Comment: Um, if its a single file why would you load it 3200 times? Just load it once outside you loop

Comment: Instead of using for loops, you could create a function that utilizes procedural recursion; that may cut down your overhead.

Comment: what's the structure of your file? Seeing that you iterate the exact same amount of lines in your file, I suspect you can just iterate once and parse everything into a Map.

Comment: It is impossible to answer unless we see some code.

Comment: what is the purpose of compare, equality?

if so, use a set. then u can find it n logn (instead of n^2)

even if not, depending on your compare reason,you can stil use a proper data structure. posting your code would help.

Comment: @DonRoby I put in the code in an edit above

Comment: The key point is that it's crazy to read the file inside the loops.  Read it into something like a HashMap and lookup inside the loop.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong: Structure is:0,1>Autauga;/n
0,2>Baldwin;/n
0,3>Barbour;/n
goes on for 3200 lines.

Comment: @kape123 I am new to android and serious java programming :)

Comment: @Simon has good recommendation - just read your file into Hashmap and then play with that. Although I think you would benefit from posting your full function on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ while saying what is that you want to do - I am sure the other part of function could also use optimizing.

Comment: Here is the whole code on codereview.stackexchange.com:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23995/optimization-of-android-code-suggestions-iteration-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd parse everything only one time, and then do with it whatever you want.

This piece of code does just that, including parsing of the `Integers` (I suspect you need these as values, not as `Strings`):

```
public void read() throws IOException {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES.txt");
    InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(iz);
    String line = "";
    String firstNumber = "";
    String secondNumber = "";
    String countyName = "";
    StringTokenizer st = null;
    HashMap<Pair, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while((line = bis.readLine()) != null) {
        st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        firstNumber = (String) st.nextElement();
        st = new StringTokenizer((String)st.nextElement(), ">");
        secondNumber = (String) st.nextElement();
        countyName = ((String) st.nextElement());
        countyName = countyName.substring(0, countyName.length()-1);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber);
        map.put(new Pair(num1, num2), countyName);
    }
}

class Pair {
    int num1, num2;
    Pair(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Pair) {
            Pair np = (Pair) other;
            return this.num1 == np.num1 && this.num2 == np.num2;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (Integer.valueOf(num1).hashCode() >> 13) ^ Integer.valueOf(num2).hashCode();
    };
}
```

Now you can simply retrieve every `countyName` with this line:

```
String s = map.get(new Pair(1,69));
```

And that returns `Aleutians East`

I hope that gets you started.

**EDIT**

This piece of code uses a 2D `SparseArray` (much like an `HashMap<Integer, Object>`). With this, everything gets sorted by the first number.

```
public class Reader {
    private String firstNumber = "";
    private String secondNumber = "";
    private String countyName = "";
    private StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = null;
    private SparseArray<SparseArray<String>> sparseArray = new SparseArray<SparseArray<String>>();
    private SparseArray<String> temporarySparseArray = null;

    public void readFromIS() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("USCOUNTIES.txt");
        InputStreamReader iz=new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(iz);
        String line = null;
        while((line = bis.readLine()) != null) {
            readLine(line);
        }
    }

    public void readFromList() {
        String[] strings = {
                "0,1>Autauga;",
                "0,2>Baldwin;",
                "0,3>Barbour;",
                "1,69>Aleutians East;",     
                "1,68>Aleutians West;"
        };
        for (String line : strings) {
            readLine(line);
        }
    }

    private void readLine(String line) {
        stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        firstNumber = (String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();
        stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer((String)stringTokenizer.nextElement(), ">");
        secondNumber = (String) stringTokenizer.nextElement();
        countyName = ((String) stringTokenizer.nextElement());
        countyName = countyName.substring(0, countyName.length()-1);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber);
        if (sparseArray.get(num1) == null) {
            sparseArray.put(num1, new SparseArray<String>());
        }
        temporarySparseArray = sparseArray.get(num1);
        temporarySparseArray.put(num2, countyName);
        sparseArray.put(num1, temporarySparseArray);
        temporarySparseArray = null;
    }

    public void test() {
        readFromList();
        String s = sparseArray.get(0).get(2);
        SparseArray sa = sparseArray.get(0);
        System.out.println(sa.size()); //should be 3
        System.out.println(s); // should be Baldwin
    }
}
```

And to retrieve all counties that start with `num1`, say, 0, you just use:

```
SparseArray<String> startingWithZero = sparseArray.get(0);
```

FYI: A `SparseArray` is a `HashMap` for `integers`, so not everything has to be autoboxed (from `Integer` to `int`, as you can't put primitive types in a `HashMap`).

**EDIT2** you print the address of the 1D sparseArray.

```
public void printEverythingStartingWithZero() {
    SparseArray<String> subSparseArray = sparseArray.get(0); //You first need a 1D sparseArray
    int key = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < subSparseArray.size(); i++) {
       key = subSparseArray.keyAt(i);
       String county = subSparseArray.get(key); //county is the String in place (0,key)
       System.out.println(county);
    }
}
```

You need to retrieve the 1D `sparseArray` first, with the leading zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code! I have a question. If I want to return all the strings which have num1=1, eg String s=map.get(new Pair(1,i)), where i is from a for loop and iterates from 0 to 3200.. Is there any better way to achieve that?

Comment: You'll have to loop either way, because you want a subset of the entire list. But maybe it's possible with a 2D `sparseArray`. Lemme check.

Comment: It's possible, see my addition.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how to print values in startingWithZero?

Comment: How to print the object that is returned? Here's the code:
        
           Object obj = sparseArray.get(key);
           System.out.println(obj);
        This is not printing anything.
Thanks!

Comment: This the output in logcat when i use obj.toString(): "D/android.util.SparseArray@40cecc88(2490)"

Comment: see addition for iterating